# unable to retrieve data from json file using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

unable to retrieve data from json file using angularjs, I'm trying to retrieve data from json file here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in names">
{{ x.eng_rev_type + ', ' + x.year_end }}
</li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://preview.sokrati.com/data/open_spendings.json")
.success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happesn when you run your code? WHat exactly did you want to happen? Whats the error?

Comment: data doesn't retrieve from json file

Comment: try `$http.get("http://preview.sokrati.com/data/open_spendings.json").then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});});`

Comment: Are you trying to perform a cross site request? If so, then this will not work.

Comment: Error: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://preview.sokrati.com/data/open_spendings.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://run.plnkr.co' is therefore not allowed access.*

Comment: Any way we can try and up this? Trying to dev some angular2 stuff and the local file seems too big.

{
"statusCode": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "Payload content length greater than maximum allowed: 1048576"
}

Answer (score -1):

try to call $apply after receiving a response.

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
```

Comment: I have edited the answer, but I think this is mostly a cross-origin issue, please check the console and look for `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin`

Comment: yes it is a cross-origin issue, so what would be the alternative solution?

Comment: I think you will need a server solution for that, to fetch the JSON data, then echo it back to the client since JSONP will not work with the URL.